# Facebook Articles Application

Tags: facebook

Recently i've noticed many news sites creating new application on facebook for sharing articles.

something like mini-site of the website inside facebook platform.

I.e Washington post application.

I've tried to find the how-to-do on facebook developers center but couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re talking about **Open Graph actions** here. Apps can define objects, and actions that can be performed on them (although fo reading an article you now have to use the build-in types), and then publish these actions on a user’s behalf.

Please familiarize yourself with the concept, start reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/